# Is it possible to redirect HTTPS to HTTP without warning?

Tags: redirects, https, security-certificate, http

One of my clients now doesn't want to use a SSL certificate. But the home page of their site has been indexed with HTTPS. I have already redirected HTTPS to HTTP but it shows a warning every time.

Is it possible to redirect without a warning?

Comment: Why don't they want to use a certificate for HTTPS?  That seems like a big step backwards, especially since you can get free certs from LetsEncrypt.

Comment: hey ! i tried to understand this to client but he doesn't want to.

Comment: So what is their reason?

Comment: Some browsers show warnings for all HTTP sites, even if you're not redirecting from HTTPS. So if they keep using the HTTP version, some visitors are going to get warnings. It's not a good idea, but to enforce HTTP you should be able to 301 redirect all HTTPS URLs to HTTP versions and use Google Search Console to set the preferred domain. Eventually the HTTPS version should drop out of the index. You might also need to ask other sites that link to the HTTPS version to update their links too, to make sure the index gets updated.

Comment: "I have already redirected HTTPS to HTTP but it shows a warning every time." What warning? With which browser?

Comment: "hey ! i tried to understand this to client but he doesn't want to." Is the client aware that all major browsers are going to display "http" websites sooner than later as "insecure" explicitely.  Does the client would like that? The world has moved towards HTTPS, there is today no reason not to do it (there were in the past at least three: performance issues because of cryptography, problem in mass virtual hosting, complexities/cost of certificates. This has been solved by faster CPUs, SNI extension, and ACME protocol respectively).

Comment: Old question, but possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147685/how-do-i-redirect-www-traffic-without-triggering-browsers-ssl-check#34148733

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a valid SSL certificate, then **it's *not* possible to redirect HTTPS to HTTP without a warning.**

To properly issue the redirect, the site needs to have a valid SSL certificate. And if the site has a valid SSL certificate, then at that point it usually makes more sense to just serve the site over HTTPS.